# VS 2015 LINK Error Cannot build project that depends on libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build a project that depends on libcurl, I have built the x64 static library of libcurl and added it to the release folder where the project expected the libcurl.lib (renamed it to curl-crt.lib as the project expected) and now I am recieving the following errors when trying to compile:

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>curl-crt.lib(easy.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strdup imported in function curl_easy_init
1>OLDNAMES.lib(strdup.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strdup imported
1>curl-crt.lib(easy.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol calloc imported in function curl_easy_init
1>curl-crt.lib(easy.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol free imported in function curl_easy_init
1>curl-crt.lib(openssl.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol free imported
1>curl-crt.lib(session.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol free imported
1>curl-crt.lib(zutil.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol free imported
1>curl-crt.lib(easy.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol malloc imported in function curl_easy_init
1>curl-crt.lib(openssl.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol malloc imported
1>curl-crt.lib(session.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol malloc imported
1>curl-crt.lib(zutil.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol malloc imported
1>curl-crt.lib(easy.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol realloc imported in function curl_easy_init
1>curl-crt.lib(session.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol realloc imported
1>curl-crt.lib(imap.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol memmove imported
1>curl-crt.lib(pingpong.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol memmove imported
1>curl-crt.lib(userauth.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol memmove imported
1>curl-crt.lib(transport.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol memmove imported
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol memmove imported in function sanitize_cookie_path
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol memmove imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol memmove imported
1>curl-crt.lib(openssl.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol memmove imported
1>curl-crt.lib(scp.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function libssh2_scp_recv
1>curl-crt.lib(socks_sspi.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(kex.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(packet.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function packet_queue_listener
1>curl-crt.lib(formdata.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(hostcheck.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_gethostname.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function Curl_ftp_parselist
1>curl-crt.lib(file.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function file_do
1>curl-crt.lib(ssh.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http_digest.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(dotdot.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(inet_pton.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function inet_pton6
1>curl-crt.lib(dict.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ldap.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(transfer.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function _vsscanf_l
1>curl-crt.lib(pipeline.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(strtok.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function Curl_cookie_add
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_sspi.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(connect.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function Curl_sndbufset
1>curl-crt.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strrchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(formdata.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strrchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(scp.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strrchr imported in function scp_recv
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strrchr imported in function Curl_cookie_add
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strrchr imported
1>curl-crt.lib(transfer.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strrchr imported in function Curl_readrewind
1>curl-crt.lib(strerror.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strrchr imported in function curl_easy_strerror
1>curl-crt.lib(knownhost.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncmp imported
1>curl-crt.lib(kex.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncmp imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncmp imported in function Curl_ftp_parselist
1>curl-crt.lib(session.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncmp imported
1>curl-crt.lib(hostkey.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncmp imported
1>curl-crt.lib(userauth.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncmp imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncmp imported
1>curl-crt.lib(mprintf.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncmp imported in function curl_mprintf
1>curl-crt.lib(rtsp.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncmp imported in function rtsp_do
1>curl-crt.lib(dotdot.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncmp imported in function Curl_dedotdotify
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncmp imported in function Curl_cookie_add
1>curl-crt.lib(vtls.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncmp imported
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncmp imported
1>curl-crt.lib(connect.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncmp imported in function Curl_is_connected
1>curl-crt.lib(formdata.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __acrt_iob_func imported
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __acrt_iob_func imported in function Curl_cookie_init
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __acrt_iob_func imported
1>curl-crt.lib(mprintf.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __acrt_iob_func imported in function _vsnprintf_l
1>curl-crt.lib(idn_win32.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __acrt_iob_func imported in function curl_win32_idn_to_ascii
1>curl-crt.lib(netrc.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fclose imported
1>curl-crt.lib(formdata.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fclose imported
1>curl-crt.lib(userauth.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fclose imported
1>curl-crt.lib(knownhost.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fclose imported
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fclose imported in function Curl_cookie_init
1>curl-crt.lib(vtls.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fclose imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fclose imported
1>curl-crt.lib(openssl.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fclose imported
1>curl-crt.lib(formdata.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fopen imported
1>curl-crt.lib(userauth.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fopen imported
1>curl-crt.lib(knownhost.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fopen imported
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fopen imported in function Curl_cookie_init
1>curl-crt.lib(vtls.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fopen imported
1>curl-crt.lib(openssl.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fopen imported
1>curl-crt.lib(netrc.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fopen imported
1>curl-crt.lib(imap.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(socks.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http_proxy.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(transfer.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported in function readwrite_data
1>curl-crt.lib(parsedate.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(rtsp.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported in function rtsp_done
1>curl-crt.lib(telnet.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported in function _vsscanf_l
1>curl-crt.lib(hostip.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported in function Curl_global_host_cache_init
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol qsort imported in function Curl_cookie_getlist
1>curl-crt.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strtoll imported in function Curl_ftp_parselist
1>curl-crt.lib(file.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoll imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ssh.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoll imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http_proxy.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoll imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http_chunks.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoll imported
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strtoll imported in function Curl_cookie_add
1>curl-crt.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoll imported
1>curl-crt.lib(imap.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoll imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoll imported
1>curl-crt.lib(packet.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _time64 imported in function _libssh2_packet_add
1>curl-crt.lib(scp.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _time64 imported in function libssh2_scp_recv
1>curl-crt.lib(agent.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _time64 imported
1>curl-crt.lib(sftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _time64 imported
1>curl-crt.lib(keepalive.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _time64 imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _time64 imported
1>curl-crt.lib(session.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _time64 imported
1>curl-crt.lib(userauth.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _time64 imported
1>curl-crt.lib(channel.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _time64 imported
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _time64 imported in function Curl_cookie_add
1>curl-crt.lib(hostip.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _time64 imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _time64 imported
1>curl-crt.lib(tftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _time64 imported
1>curl-crt.lib(asyn-thread.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _errno imported in function init_resolve_thread
1>curl-crt.lib(http_chunks.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _errno imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _errno imported in function Curl_ftp_parselist
1>curl-crt.lib(hostip.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol tolower imported in function Curl_cache_addr
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol tolower imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncpy imported
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_sspi.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncpy imported in function Curl_create_sspi_identity
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncpy imported
1>curl-crt.lib(strerror.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncpy imported in function Curl_strerror
1>curl-crt.lib(telnet.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncpy imported
1>curl-crt.lib(userauth.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fread imported
1>curl-crt.lib(vtls.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fread imported in function Curl_pin_peer_pubkey
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fread imported
1>curl-crt.lib(transfer.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fread imported
1>curl-crt.lib(formdata.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fread imported in function Curl_getformdata
1>curl-crt.lib(vtls.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fseek imported in function Curl_pin_peer_pubkey
1>curl-crt.lib(transfer.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fseek imported
1>curl-crt.lib(vtls.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ftell imported in function Curl_pin_peer_pubkey
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isalpha imported in function parse_proxy
1>curl-crt.lib(parsedate.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isalpha imported
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isalpha imported
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isxdigit imported in function parse_proxy
1>curl-crt.lib(escape.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isxdigit imported
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isxdigit imported
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strpbrk imported in function parseurlandfillconn
1>curl-crt.lib(ssh.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strpbrk imported in function ssh_connect
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fwrite imported in function Curl_init_userdefined
1>curl-crt.lib(sendf.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fwrite imported
1>curl-crt.lib(knownhost.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fwrite imported
1>curl-crt.lib(scp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
1>curl-crt.lib(tftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
1>curl-crt.lib(smtp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strtol imported in function parse_proxy
1>curl-crt.lib(pipeline.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strtol imported in function Curl_pipeline_server_blacklisted
1>curl-crt.lib(parsedate.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
1>curl-crt.lib(mprintf.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strtoul imported in function parseurlandfillconn
1>curl-crt.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoul imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ssh.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strtoul imported in function ssh_block_statemach
1>curl-crt.lib(escape.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoul imported
1>curl-crt.lib(connect.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol atoi imported in function bindlocal
1>curl-crt.lib(telnet.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol atoi imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
1>curl-crt.lib(smtp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ssh.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isdigit imported in function ssh_statemach_act
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_sasl.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isdigit imported in function Curl_http_readwrite_headers
1>curl-crt.lib(parsedate.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
1>curl-crt.lib(mprintf.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isdigit imported in function dprintf_Pass1
1>curl-crt.lib(imap.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
1>curl-crt.lib(userauth.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isspace imported in function file_read_publickey
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_sasl_sspi.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ssh.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isspace imported in function get_pathname
1>curl-crt.lib(http_digest.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_ntlm.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http_negotiate_sspi.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isspace imported in function Curl_add_custom_headers
1>curl-crt.lib(rtsp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
1>curl-crt.lib(file.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
1>curl-crt.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol memchr imported in function Curl_http_readwrite_headers
1>curl-crt.lib(tftp.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol memchr imported in function tftp_doing
1>curl-crt.lib(userauth.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol memchr imported in function file_read_publickey
1>curl-crt.lib(progress.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fflush imported in function Curl_pgrsUpdate
1>curl-crt.lib(parsedate.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isalnum imported in function parsedate
1>curl-crt.lib(rtsp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isalnum imported
1>curl-crt.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isalnum imported
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isalnum imported
1>curl-crt.lib(mprintf.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fputc imported in function curl_mfprintf
1>curl-crt.lib(knownhost.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(agent.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(mprintf.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf imported in function _vsnprintf_l
1>curl-crt.lib(misc.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(channel.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(scp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf imported
1>curl-crt.lib(file.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _lseeki64 imported in function file_do
1>curl-crt.lib(file.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _fstat64 imported in function file_do
1>curl-crt.lib(idn_win32.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vfwprintf imported in function _vfwprintf_l
1>curl-crt.lib(getenv.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol getenv imported in function GetEnv
1>curl-crt.lib(formdata.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _stat64 imported in function AddFormData
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_sasl.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isupper imported in function Curl_sasl_decode_mech
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isupper imported
1>curl-crt.lib(userauth.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol feof imported in function file_read_publickey
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol islower imported in function loop
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isprint imported in function loop
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isgraph imported in function loop
1>OLDNAMES.lib(strdup.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _strdup imported
1>OLDNAMES.lib(read.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _read imported
1>OLDNAMES.lib(write.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _write imported
1>OLDNAMES.lib(stricmp.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _stricmp imported
1>OLDNAMES.lib(strnicmp.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _strnicmp imported
1>OLDNAMES.lib(close.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _close imported
1>OLDNAMES.lib(open.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _open imported
1>OLDNAMES.lib(access.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _access imported
1>Download.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lzma_code referenced in function "unsigned __int64 __cdecl DL_WriteToFile(void *,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,struct _iobuf *)" (?DL_WriteToFile@@YA_KPEAX_K1PEAU_iobuf@@@Z)
1>InstallerExtraction.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol lzma_code
1>Download.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lzma_end referenced in function "void __cdecl DL_ProcessDownload(void)" (?DL_ProcessDownload@@YAXXZ)
1>InstallerExtraction.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol lzma_end
1>Download.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lzma_stream_decoder referenced in function "void __cdecl DL_ProcessDownload(void)" (?DL_ProcessDownload@@YAXXZ)
1>InstallerExtraction.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lzma_alone_decoder referenced in function "public: __cdecl LzmaStreamWrapper::LzmaStreamWrapper(struct _iobuf *)" (??0LzmaStreamWrapper@@QEAA@PEAU_iobuf@@@Z)
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fgets referenced in function Curl_cookie_init
1>curl-crt.lib(netrc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fgets
1>curl-crt.lib(knownhost.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fgets
1>curl-crt.lib(cookie.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fputs referenced in function cookie_output
1>curl-crt.lib(tftp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strstr referenced in function tftp_rx
1>curl-crt.lib(ftp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strstr
1>curl-crt.lib(ssh.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strstr
1>curl-crt.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strstr
1>curl-crt.lib(vtls.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strstr
1>curl-crt.lib(url.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strstr
1>curl-crt.lib(http.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strstr
1>curl-crt.lib(transfer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strstr
1>curl-crt.lib(warnless.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_read referenced in function curlx_read
1>OLDNAMES.lib(read.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_read
1>curl-crt.lib(warnless.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_write referenced in function curlx_write
1>OLDNAMES.lib(write.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_write
1>curl-crt.lib(strequal.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_stricmp referenced in function curl_strequal
1>OLDNAMES.lib(stricmp.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_stricmp
1>curl-crt.lib(strequal.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strnicmp referenced in function curl_strnequal
1>OLDNAMES.lib(strnicmp.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strnicmp
1>curl-crt.lib(parsedate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__gmtime64 referenced in function Curl_gmtime
1>curl-crt.lib(strerror.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strerror referenced in function Curl_strerror
1>curl-crt.lib(strerror.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___sys_nerr referenced in function Curl_strerror
1>curl-crt.lib(curl_threads.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__beginthreadex referenced in function Curl_thread_create
1>curl-crt.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_close referenced in function file_done
1>OLDNAMES.lib(close.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_close
1>curl-crt.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_open referenced in function file_connect
1>OLDNAMES.lib(open.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_open
1>curl-crt.lib(ssh.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strspn referenced in function get_pathname
1>curl-crt.lib(ssh.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_access referenced in function ssh_statemach_act
1>OLDNAMES.lib(access.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_access
1>curl-crt.lib(session.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__difftime64 referenced in function _libssh2_wait_socket
1>curl-crt.lib(userauth.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_rewind referenced in function file_read_publickey
```

Following **GuidedHacking** answer this is the result:

https://pastebin.com/khg4Bh9k

Comment: Presumably the project is configured to use a different runtime library setting to curl, they need to be the same

Comment: @AlanBirtles there is a curl vcxproj but when I compile it it simply copies 1 file. This is what I could find in the settings of this vcxproj:Build Events:Pre-Build Event: command line : 'copy /y "$(ProjectDir)\..\..\..\vendor\curl\include\curl\curlbuild.h.dist" "$(ProjectDir)\..\..\..\vendor\curl\include\curl\curlbuild.h"'  .Librarian - Command line: '/OUT:"..\..\bin\PROJ\release\curl-crt.lib" /MACHINE:X64 /NOLOGO ' . I am sorry for this formatting, I cannot add paragraphs in this reply.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your linker command line:

```
/NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After adding that to the linker command line: https://pastebin.com/khg4Bh9k